# OpsHub migration failed: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Could not find a part of the path 'O:\w37_1\{ProjName}'

Tags: tfs, migration, opshub

I can't continue with the migration because of this error, I already tried to give permissions in the **TFS_Folder** folder, I also tried into a VM with an admin user but still.

What else can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share some more log traces? Also, the utility will try to map a drive (either O:, P: etc based on availability), does your user have necessary privilege for that?

Comment: Suggest you add more detail info such as the detail scenario, environment you are working on, such as you are trying to do which migration, from xx to xx ?

Comment: I'll make a clean instalation on a new VM to give you the logs and more details